# Objective-C block used strong variables

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

i want to understand  that which function is correct , and hope some people can give me advice between func1 and func2.

now i used func1, some people told me the func2 have memory problem.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *NameAndIdDictionary;
 - (void) func1 
 {
    __weak NSDictionary *NameAndIdDictionary = self.NameAndIdDictionary;
     self.Keys = [[NameAndIdDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSString *name1 = (NSString *)NameAndIdDictionary[obj1];
        NSString *name2 = (NSString *)NameAndIdDictionary[obj2];
        return [[name1 uppercaseString] compare:[name2 uppercaseString]];
    }];
 }


 - (void) func2
 {
     self.Keys = [[self.NameAndIdDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSString *name1 = (NSString *)self.NameAndIdDictionary[obj1];
        NSString *name2 = (NSString *)self.NameAndIdDictionary[obj2];
        return [[name1 uppercaseString] compare:[name2 uppercaseString]];
    }];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`func2` is fine. `sortedArrayUsingComparator` does not store the block for later use or anything like that, so there is no issue of retain cycles.

Comment: Thank you, that mean i can use any variable in this block, example , i can add new object in NameAndIdDictionary in block.

Comment: or only sortedArrayUsingComparator this block is fine , another block will be have issue or retain cycles problem.